# catkin_make is not building my bitbucket based ros packages

Tags: ros, drone, git, ardrone-autonomy, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Background

I have an existing project that I want to migrate to a different computer. I started building a project on my Raspberry Pi and then put the project up on **github**. The current name of the project/package is `zlab_drone`. Here is the hierarchy of my project

```
                                         /home 
                                            |
                                        /catkin_ws
                                            |
     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                                      |                                         |
  /devel                                  /src                                     /build
     |                                      |                                         |
    ...                        -----------------------------                         ...
                               |             |             |
                  CMakeLists.txt     /ardrone_autonomy     /zlab_drone
```

### Main Issue

Now my problem is the fact that whenever I clone my `/zlab` folder into my `/src` folder on a different computer and run catkin_make in my `/catkin_ws` folder, it does not build the `/zlab_drone` package that I have cloned.  However, if I build the whole thing from ground up, using `catkin_create_package`, `catkin_make` recognizes the package `/zlab_drone`. In fact, to get ardrone_autonomy, I just `git` cloned it into my `/src` folder. Not sure why this isn't working for `/zlab_drone`.

### Solutions that I have tried out

Looking at the `CMakeLists.txt` present in `ardrone_autonomy`, I noticed that they had this little section:

```
# Build [pathced] ardronelib from an external project
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(ardronelib
    GIT_REPOSITORY git://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardronelib.git
    GIT_TAG 2f987029c55531e4c0119c3600f9c57f935851ed
    PREFIX ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND echo "No configure"
    BUILD_COMMAND make
    INSTALL_COMMAND make install INSTALL_PREFIX=${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/lib/ardrone
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
)
```

I modified this for the current project that I am looking at:

```
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(zlab_drone
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://bitbucket.org/sharan_duggirala/zlab_drone
    PREFIX ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND echo "No configure"
    BUILD_COMMAND make
    INSTALL_COMMAND make install INSTALL_PREFIX=${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/lib/zlab_drone
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
)
```

Now the problem I face is that whenever I get the prompt for `Username for 'https://bitbucket.org'` `catkin_make` continues with `Building ARDroneTool/Lib`. I am going to try this out with *github* and check if a similar problem persists. However, I would like to discover a way to use *bitbucket*, as it allows private projects and such.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254149/catkin_make-is-not-building-my-bitbucket-based-ros-packages/) by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2017-02-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-02-08**:
Does your zlab project contain a package.xml and a CMakeLists.txt ? If it doesn't have a package.xml, or it isn't checked into git, catkin_make won't recognize it as a package and won't build it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found your project on github: https://github.com/sd12832/zlab_drone and it seems like there are no build commands in your CMakeLists.txt . It looks like your project isn't building because there are no build commands.

The ardrone package is using the ExternalProjectAdd command to download and build a second, separate repository that is not a ROS package (note that the git URL that they're pulling from isn't the same as the URL for their ROS package). Since all of your code is in one package, you don't need to do this.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-09**:
Yup, that was exactly why nothing was being built. Not sure why github missed out on those commands.